# Extracting text string between 2 characters with Regex

Tags: json, regex

Say I have this string:

```
["teads.tv, 15429, reseller, 15a9c44f6d26cbe1 ","video.unrulymedia.com,367782854,reseller","google.com, pub-8173359565788166, direct, f08c47fec0942fa0","google.com, pub-8804303781641925, reseller, f08c47fec0942fa0 "]
```

I am trying to extract all the text strings like teads.tv, google.com and etc.
Each text string is placed in the following way **"**text.text**,**, but there are aslo combinations of ", without any character in between.

I tried this Regex expression:

```
"(.*?)\,
```

but I also capture the empty combinations, you can check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/5ZU7H4/1).

How can I modify the Regex expression, so it would capture only the combination with a string between ",?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there should be at least a single non whitespace char present other than `"` `,` `[` `]` you can match optional whitespace chars and use a negated character class listing all the characters that should not be matched and repeat that 1 or more times.

```
"(\s*[^\][\s",]+),
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zXnDz7/1)

The more broad variation is to repeat 1+ times any char except a comma:

```
"([^,]+),
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Ql6dM/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `+` (one or more) instead of `*` (zero or more) as quantifier:

```
"(.+?),
```

Additionally, you may not need to escape `,` with backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question as retrieving the string with a dotted notation such as domain names means that we are looking for the first string after a `"`.
This string will grab strings with dots within them, but avoid the quote characters.

```js
const regEx = /(?:\")([\w\d\.\-]+)/g;
const input = '["teads.tv, 15429, reseller, 15a9c44f6d26cbe1 ","video.unrulymedia.com,367782854,reseller","google.com, pub-8173359565788166, direct, f08c47fec0942fa0","google.com, pub-8804303781641925, reseller, f08c47fec0942fa0 "]';
const regMatch = Array.from(input.matchAll(regEx), m => m[1]);
console.log(regMatch)
```